# The usage of Past Simple and Past Perfect Continuous

Tags: tense, past-tense

A quote from a movie:

> We were married for 10 years.

Why can we use the Past Simple tense for an action which had been taking place for a certain time? The emphasis is on the duration, so according to what I was taught it should be:

> We had been married for 10 years.

When and why can we use the past simple tense instead of the past perfect continous.

It just doesn't seem right to me to say:

> I was cleaning the windows for three hours.

Comment: Why shouldn't I tag my question as grammar-related? It refers to grammar.

Comment: We are deleting the "grammar" tag, because it's too generic. 90% of the question on this site are grammar-related, and tagging them with "grammar" is useless. This tag won't help users find similar questions.

Comment: Then when should I use the "grammar" tag?

Comment: Only when you can't think of a more specific tag. Experienced users then will replace this tag with a more specific one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use the simple past when speaking in the present. For instance, you're at a bar with a friend, and you see a woman and she waves at you. Your friend asks if you know her, and you say "Of course I **know** her - we **were married** for ten years." You say that because in that moment you are speaking in the present, using the present form **know**, about something that happened in the past and then ended.

However, if you and your friend are talking about your first marriage and how it ended, you would tell him the story **in the past**, using past forms:

"We **were living** in New York and I **was** always going out with other women. My wife **found out** and **asked** me for a divorce. We **had been married** for ten years."

Here, you use the past perfect because you're talking **in the past** about something that happened, or started happening, *before* that past, i.e. before the point in the past when your wife asked you for the divorce.

Comment: Does it mean that the fact that an action lasted for some time and finished in the past isn't enough to use the Past Perfect tense?

Comment: It is enough, as long as the context is already the past. For instance, in my account, the speaker's marriage lasted some time and ended, so he used the past perfect while speaking about the past. The past perfect can be viewed as a back story to something that happened in the past.